# XHR failed loading: POST jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, http

Привет) Пытаюсь зарегать пользователя из формы таким вот способом:

```
const serverAddress = "http://localhost:8080";
        const registerAddress = "/register";

        $("#registration").submit(function () {
            let registerUserDto = {
                "firstName":$("#firstName").val(),
                "lastName":$("#lastName").val(),
                "username":$("#registerUsername").val(),
                "password":$("#registerPassword").val(),
                "repeatPassword":$("#repeatPassword").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: serverAddress + registerAddress,
                method: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(registerUserDto),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                statusCode: {
                    400: function () {
                        $("#badCredentials").text("Bad credentials");
                    },
                    201: function () {
                        alert("Nice!");
                        window.location = 'login.html';
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Когда форма регистрации сабмитится, срабатывает функция которая выдергивает значеия с полей, конвертит в json и отправляет на сервер. Но когда я нажимаю кнопочку, вот что происходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это значит и как это можно пофиксить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $("#registration").submit(function (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      ...
```

Comment: Супер! все заработало!!) Спасибо) только за сегодня и начала jquery юзать